# One of the query in Union returns no results in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I have a union query with 2 select queries.

sample query:

```
(SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 where column1 = 1)
UNION
(SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2 WHERE column1 = 100);
```

Let's say one of the above queries does not return the result (i.e. No rows found).

I just want the result from one of the queries that return data.

Comment: Remove the ()'s?  Provided column1 and column2 types are the same this union should work.  A union still works if no records are returned from 1 select

Comment: it should work even with parenthesis. what's the problem?..

Comment: Be sure to have thesame columns in the select

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around each select are useless.

Comment: Are you sure any rows available with column value with 1 and 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `union all` unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Second, the `union`/`union all` should be fine, even if one of the subqueries returns no rows.  It will returns the rows from the other subquery.